# url links in struts2 tiles gets namespace added on second time after click. How do I stop this?

Tags: struts2, namespaces, tiles

I am using struts 2, tiles, and namespaces and am having a problem that after I click a link the menu appends the namespace a second time. I am using the struts tag url with an action and a namespace.  When the page is first displayed, the links in the menu are correct land have the namespace before the action.  After I click on one of the links, the page redisplays and although the source looks okay, when I hover over it firefox shows the url with the namespace in there twice.  I.E.

localhost/ar/customermaint becomes localhost/ar/ar/customermaint.  If I have clicked on a link that has a different namespace such as "ss" first then it becomes localhost/ss/ar/customermaint.

any idea what I'm doing wrong? Or is it a problem with tiles and namespaces.

Comment: Nothing to do with tiles, name your struts2 namespaces with a leading '/' if you don't, this is the expected behaviour... why I'm not sure so I just name everything with a '/'

Comment: I found out the problem.  Namespaces must be relative  in my url namespace field I had namespace="ss"  When I changed it to namespace="/ss" it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this issue before. Each time when the action is called, the namespace gets appended in the URL and it looked ugly

Example: `http://localhost:8080/RmAirlines/user/user/user/user/user/login` for calling the action `login` from a namespace `user` each time

Setting the namespace to "/" isn't an ideal solution either.

**Solution:** Suppose the `namespace` of the `package` is `"/user"` and there's an `action` named `"login"` inside it (in your `struts.xml`). Then where ever you call the `action`, refer it as `action="/user/login"` (or `action="/user/login.action"`) - i.e. putting a "/" before the namespace will save your day!

**Example:**

struts.xml

```
<package name="userManagement" namespace="/user" extends="struts-default">      
        <action name="login" class="com.rm.airlines.action.Login">
            <result name="success">/user.jsp</result>
            <result name="login">/login.jsp</result>
        </action>       
</package>
```

login.jsp

```
<s:form action="/user/login">
        <s:textfield label="Email" key="email" />
        <s:password label="Password" key="password" />
        <s:submit />
</s:form>
```

Comment: There is `namespace` attribute in some S2 tags exactly for that.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this, always follow a simple principle.

For all namespace declaration, use a slash "/" followed by the namespace name.
In this way, it will not append the earlier namespace in new url.

What struts assume, if you don't specify "/" in new namespace, it tries to find it in currently used namespace. If you specify "/" before namespace name, it takes it as a root namespace.

Example:-

```
<package name="default" namespace="/nsp" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="validate" class="login.LoginAction">
    <result name="success">/home.jsp</result>
    <result name="login">/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
<package name="cricket" namespace="/cricket" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="findcaptain" class="cricket.CaptainAction">
    <result>/showCaptain.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

Look in each of my package declaration, I am using namespace name prefixed by a slash. i.e. /nsp and /cricket). And that's how we could avoid this namespace appending issue.